# Get event when file is copied to watched directory

Tags: c#, .net-core, filesystemwatcher

I am creating a service, that will watch specified directory for any changed (for instance, file created, renamed, etc). I extended FileSystemWatcher class, and my main Watch method is this:

```
public void Watch() {
    Path = "C:\\Users\\Golobitch\\Documents\\ProSyncTest\\";

    NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    Filter = "*";

    Changed += OnChanged;
    Created += OnChanged;
    Deleted += OnChanged;
    Renamed += OnRenamed;

    EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.Name} {e.ChangeType}");
}

private void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine($"File: {e.OldFullPath} renamed to {e.FullPath}");
}
```

Ok great, so this is working. Whenever there is new file or something like that, proper method will be called. But how about if I copy large file from USB to this watched directory? Then I get these notifications:

```
File: Ubuntu 18 LTS dev.vdi Created
File: Ubuntu 18 LTS dev.vdi Changed
File: Ubuntu 18 LTS dev.vdi Changed
```

So I actually don't know when file is completely transfered over to my directory. Is there some solution, some event that I can hook up to?

Edit: Should I check if file is locked by another process?